# What are the numbers after the hyphen on an IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, datasheet, rom

I am new to electronics and picked up some older ICs to learn more about them. I came across one with the following serial number: `MR53V8052J-77R`
I did some research and it seems like it is an 8mb ROM chip, however only the numbers before the hyphen are written on the datasheet I found online. I've had similar situations before and I'm afraid I have the wrong datasheet, so, what do the numbers / letters after the hyphen mean? Are they that important or can I leave them out when searching for datasheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single device often comes in multiple different variants that share a single datasheet. The variants might be the exact same IC in different packages, or they might differ in other ways.

For devices like these, the datasheet usually has an "Ordering Information" section which describes the variable portion of the part number and what each part of it means. So, look in the ordering information section of your datasheet and see if it explains what "77R" means.

Answer (score 2):

There's no blanket rule. Some devices don't even have a dash.

With memory devices it is common that the suffix information is the access speed and maybe the packaging.

Comment: Thanks, so I can safely use the datasheet I found?

Comment: What does the datasheet say? If there's options, then the datasheet will usually outline that.

Comment: It just has the numbers before the hyphen as a heading and the default information (Maximum ratings, pinout etc.). It doesn't seem like there are other options

Comment: first page shows the options. The R is a 42 pin DIP. The 77 probably denotes what's programmed into it. The likes of Nintendo would ask OKI to make them a million chips with the Super Mario game in them, so that would have a different suffix to Asteroids. The chip is the same, but the data programmed into it is different, so not interchangeable.